# Editing Magento EE recurring profiles Add To Cart Button

Tags: magento-enterprise, recurring

We are looking to use the Magento EE recurring profiles function to enable people to buy/sign up to recieve a product automatically shipped to them monthly.

However I noticed that enabling the recurring profiles function results in the page having two "add to cart" buttons. Which could cause some confusion by the customer knowing which button is which.

I tried looking for where the html code was for the recurring profiles add to cart button but could not find it. Does anyone know where the code is for the button so that it can be edited (want to change the text label on it)

Comment: Could you show how this looks on your site? I see recurring profile product in Magento demo data on rwd theme has one button there.

Answer (score 0):

The template of the button can easily be determined by using [Template Path Hints](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/template-path-hints.html)